# How to staple different plots at same size with diferent alignments in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am new to ggplot. I want to put multiple plot in a row, some wear y axis descriptions (the  y axis of first plot is different from the others), on the far right side, there is a group descriptions (last one),actually everything's fine,  **but I want all panels to have the same panel (width) size.**

I think I know my mistake, ggplots thinks my subplots as fixed squares, but I don't know how to fix it.

See the picture and you may quickly see my problem.

[image]

Here's my r code

```
######################

    library(ggplot2)  
    require(ggplot2)
    library(gridExtra)
    require(gridExtra)

Leader = ForkinDatenHase$Leader

leaderPlot<-(ggplot() + aes(x = ForkinDatenHase$Pos, color = ForkinDatenHase$Sex, group = ForkinDatenHase$Sex, y = Leader) +
      stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point") + 
      labs(title = "Leader", x="Physician's posture") +
      stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line") + 
      theme(legend.position = "none",axis.title.y = element_blank())+
      scale_y_discrete(Leader, limits=c("1"="Not chosen", "2"="Chosen")) +
      scale_color_discrete(name = "Sex of physician", labels = c("female physician", "male physician")) +
      coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 2))#+
    
)
leaderPlot


powerPlot<-(ggplot() + aes(x = Posture, color = Sex, group = Sex, y = Pow) +
                            stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point") +
                            stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line") + 
                            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1.5, 3.5)) +
                            labs(title = "Power", x="Physician's posture") +
                            theme(legend.position = "none",axis.title.y = element_blank())+
                            scale_y_discrete(breaks=c("1","2","3","4"),labels=c("4th rank", "3rd rank", "2nd rank", "1st rank")) #+
                            #scale_color_discrete(name = "Sex of physician", labels = c("female physician", "male physician"))
                )
powerPlot

conPlot<-(ggplot() + aes(x = Posture, color = Sex, group = Sex, y = Con) +
              stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point") +
              stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line") + 
              coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1.5, 3.5)) +
              labs(title = "Confidence", x="Physician's posture") +
              theme(legend.position = "none", axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())#+
              #scale_y_discrete(breaks=c("1","2","3","4"),labels=c("4th rank", "3rd rank", "2nd rank", "1st rank")) #+
            #scale_color_discrete(name = "Sex of physician", labels = c("female physician", "male physician"))
)
conPlot
      

conInt<-(ggplot() + aes(x = Posture, color = Sex, group = Sex, y = Int) +
            stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point") +
            stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line") + 
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1.5, 3.5)) +
            labs(title = "Intelligence", x="Physician's posture") +
            theme(legend.position = "none", axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())#+
          #scale_y_discrete(breaks=c("1","2","3","4"),labels=c("4th rank", "3rd rank", "2nd rank", "1st rank")) #+
          #scale_color_discrete(name = "Sex of physician", labels = c("female physician", "male physician"))
)
conInt

 


conSco<-(ggplot() + aes(x = Posture, color = Sex, group = Sex, y = EBD) +
           stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point") +
           stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "line") + 
           coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1.5, 3.5)) +
           labs(title = "Confidence", x="Physician's posture") +
           theme( axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank())+
         #scale_y_discrete(breaks=c("1","2","3","4"),labels=c("4th rank", "3rd rank", "2nd rank", "1st rank")) #+
         scale_color_discrete(name = "Sex of physician", labels = c("female physician", "male physician"))
)
conSco

plot1<-grid.arrange(leaderPlot, powerPlot, conPlot,conInt, conSco, nrow = 1)
```

Comment: Hi Felix. It would be much easier to help if you include the data in your question. Try typing `dput(ForkinDatenHase)` into the console, then copying and pasting the result into your question.

Comment: Have a look at the patchwork package: https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork. It is very convenient for aligned plot composition.

Comment: @AllanCameron My data set is to big. How can I cut out minimal sample?

Comment: @teunbrand. wow, it works! I will mutiple figures, how can I ensure, that the plots will have the same size?

Comment: I think setting fixed aspect ratios might help, but I'm not 100% sure how to achieve that.

Comment: `dput(ForkinDatenHase)` and paste the output in the post to help you!

Answer (score 0):

the package patchwork brings the solution. It's powerful enough to  arrange the plots correctly. Thanks and kudos to @teunbrand